# hovers don't work

Tags: jquery

Below is the code I'm using for the hovers:

---

Can someone help me identify the problem? If I left out any important info, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Try downloading updates from Windows Update. Had a similar issue - gone after updates.

Comment: @Nux The only update listed is KB2785094 and it fails to update every time. I looked into it and it seems a lot of people are having the same problem. Is this the update you're talking about?

Comment: Updating Windows 8 Enterprise worked fine for me just today and at least one update was for IE. The site I was working on haven't worked before and magically started to work after update so I guess something was fixed :-)...

Comment: But... Shouldn't that be just `$(function(){` not `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove jQuery(document).ready(function($){ and the closing braces at the end. You're binding an event handler to the onhover event, you don't need to do anything on $(document).ready().